# Returning pairs of _id's of duplicate docs found by a specific field on mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

During DB data migration I'm running these days, I've found docs that remain in the collection that should not be there anymore.

I succeeded to find duplicates by unitId field, using the following MongoDB aggregation method via MongoShell.

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
{"$group" : { "_id": "$unitId", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }, 
{"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
{"$project": {"id" : "$_id", "_id" : 0} } 
).toArray()
```

This query returns:

```
[{"unitId" : ObjectId("5cfcf47043289e2b4db14d5d")}...]
```

But I do not want to delete duplications that I found.

instead, I want to merge those into one doc full of necessary data.

I'm want to get a result like the following or something similar to:

`[{_id1: 'xxxxxxxxxx', _id2: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'}...]`

I thought it would be great that Mongo will return this data in one query. instead of searching again through the array of the results.

Thanks in advance (:

Comment: you want to actually merge them? or just for the sake of the aggregation to have them merged?

Comment: Just get the _id's of the docs that are duplicate, the merge needs to go through a 2nd function because it depends on the data itself

Comment: you can just push them when you group: `{"$group" : { "_id": "$unitId", "count": { "$sum": 1 }, docs: {$push: "$_id"} } }` just dont forget to project them aswel.